Docker volume mounted as :ro is still writeable
I have a data folder at the root of my filesystem
arthur@debian:~$ ls -la /data
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  9 root   root            4096 Dec 13 09:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root            4096 Dec 13 10:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root            4096 Jun 15  2020 500g2
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root            4096 Nov 16 18:20 quad_1
drwxr-sr-x  5 arthur arthur          4096 Dec 13 13:29 tera_1
drwxrwxr-x  6 root   root            4096 Dec  7 00:00 tera_2
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root            4096 Sep 18 21:32 tera_3
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root            4096 May  5  2021 tera_4

I want to mount the entire directory as a docker volume, but the container must have readonly access. So I used :ro
sudo docker run -it --name testcontainer -v /data:/internal_data:ro --rm alpine:latest /bin/sh

When the shell spawns, I'm still able to write into the supposedly readonly container. Why is that ?
/ # touch /internal_data/test
touch: /internal_data/test: Read-only file system        # Ok, container prevented from writing
/ # touch /internal_data/tera_1/test                     # This worked
/ # touch /internal_data/tera_2/test                     # This worked
/ # touch /internal_data/500g2/test                      
touch: /internal_data/500g2/test: Read-only file system # Ok, container prevented from writing
/ #


Are the tera_1 and tera_2 directories mountpoints for other filesystems?

Yes, those are disks mounted at those specific points. All of those are in the same filesystem (ext4).

I'm confused by your last statement: if tera_1 and tera_2 are mountpoints, then they are not in the same filesystem. They are distinct filesystems from /data, and that may be why they are still writeable even though /internal_data is not. I'll have to test that out later today to be sure.

They refer to hard disks that I have mounted at this specific point. When I add their parent directory /data/ as readonly, I supposed the entire content (recursively) of that directory would be readonly for the container. Turns out the fact that it is an additional filesystem seems to throw Docker off ..

You need a 5.12 or greater kernel version and docker version 25 or greater to support recursive read-only bind mounts.
$ uname -v
#1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.119-1 (2024-11-22)

$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           27.3.1
 API version:       1.47
 Go version:        go1.22.7
 Git commit:        ce12230
 Built:             Fri Sep 20 11:41:11 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          27.3.1
  API version:      1.47 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.22.7
  Git commit:       41ca978
  Built:            Fri Sep 20 11:41:11 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.24
  GitCommit:        88bf19b2105c8b17560993bee28a01ddc2f97182
 runc:
  Version:          1.2.2
  GitCommit:        v1.2.2-0-g7cb3632
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

$ mount
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3159048k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/mapper/xxxx-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
....

$ docker run -it --rm -v /:/host:ro alpine

/ # cd /host
/host # touch test
touch: test: Read-only file system

/host # cd run

/host/run # touch test
touch: test: Read-only file system

See also Docker's docs on recursive bind mounts.

Huh .. I hadn't stumbled on that part of the docs until now. I'll try to update my kernel and if that doesn't break anything (lol) I'll mark this answer as accepted.
